# UWP StartBringIntoView not working in Page_Loaded

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

I have 3 `BladeItem`s in another page. And I want to navigate from `MainPage` to that page and bring the requested `BladeItem` into view. But it is not working.

I first thought it was because that the page has not been loaded. So I put it into the Page_Loaded. However, it is still now working. Why is that?

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TitleBarHelper.SetDarkTitleBar();
        Window.Current.SetTitleBar(AppTitleBar);
        UpdateTitleBarLayout(Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar);

        FullMediaControl.Update();
        SetMusic(MediaHelper.CurrentMusic);
        FullPlaylistControl.ScrollToMusic(MediaHelper.CurrentMusic);

        if (MusicInfoRequestedWhenUnloaded)
        {
            MusicPropertyBladeItem.StartBringIntoView();
            MusicInfoRequestedWhenUnloaded = false;
        }
        else if (LyricsRequestedWhenUnloaded)
        {
            LyricsBladeItem.StartBringIntoView();
            LyricsRequestedWhenUnloaded = false;
        }
    }
```

Source Page Code is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/NowPlayingFullPage.xaml.cs). This page can be navigated using the "Show Lyrics" or "Music Info" item in the `MenuFlyout` at the right bottom more button.

And actually the `FullPlaylistControl.ScrollToMusic` in the code above is also not working. It just scrolls to a row in a `ListView`. I guess they might be the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the documentation for [StartBringIntoView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.startbringintoview).

According to the instructions in the documentation, this method is only possible when the control is rendered on the visual tree, so you need to modify it when you call the method.

You want `MusicPropertyBladeItem.StartBringIntoView()` to work, you need to call it in the `MusicPropertyBladeItem_Loaded` event. For the same reason, you need to call `ScrollToMusic` when the `FullPlaylistControl` is loaded.

`Page_Loaded` only means that the page is loaded, but it doesn't mean that the controls have been rendered.

Best ragards.

Comment: Thanks. Using Loaded event works for the `BladeItem`s. But it doesn't seem to work for the `ScrollToMusic`, maybe because I used `ListView.ScrollIntoView`?

Comment: Hi, `ScrollToMusic` should be your own method, essentially `ListView.ScrollIntoView()`. So you need to call it in the `ListView.Loaded` event.

Comment: Yes it is in the `Loaded` event but still not working. You can see from the code at the bottom [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControl.xaml.cs)

Comment: I think you can debug and see if `ScrollToMusicRequestedWhenUnloaded` is `null` in `ListView_Loaded`. But does not rule out the exceptions that may occur during the rendering process. After all, `ScrollIntoView` does not return a value and will not report an error. I created a new ListView and generated 200 entries. In the ListView.Loaded event, I can successfully call `ScrollIntoView`. You can also create a new project to test.

Comment: It is not null but I found out that `SongsListView.ContainerFromItem(ScrollToMusicRequestedWhenUnloaded)` gives me null. It doesn't seem to find it but I do have that in the `ListView`. Why?

Comment: Is it because that item has not been loaded?

Comment: I speculate that this may be due to virtualization, but no documentation has been found so far. But it is certain that if the corresponding list item is not rendered in the ListView, then it will not successfully call `ScrollIntoView`.

Comment: I have found a workaround, which is to put `SongsListView.ContainerFromIndex() is ListViewItem container` in the `ListViewItem_Loaded` to determine if the item is loaded. I am able to bring it into view by calling `container.StartBringIntoView();` but still fails to call `ScrollIntoView`.